# Ordering query result by field from a different table (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a MySQL table structure and need to get a specific query working but I just can't wrap my head around it somehow. First off, here's the relevant table structure.

folders:

```
+--------------+--------------+
| Field        | Type         |
+--------------+--------------+
| id           | int(11)      |
| project_id   | int(11)      |
| finished     | int(11)      |
| approved     | int(11)      |
| comment      | varchar(500) |
+--------------+--------------+
```

werte:

```
+---------------------+---------------+
| Field               | Type          |
+---------------------+---------------+
| id                  | int(11)       |
| folder_id           | int(11)       |
| form_id             | int(11)       |
| werte               | varchar(5000) |
| number              | int(11)       |
+---------------------+---------------+
```

Now I have a situation where I want to retrieve the *id* field from *folders* in a certain order. The first couple of sortings I need are easy to achieve, since the order is determined by fields in the table. For example

```
SELECT id FROM folders ORDER BY approved ASC;
```

However I need another ordering where the *id*s are sorted by a value in the *werte* column from the *werte* table. To make it a bit less abstract, the *werte* table holds parameter values, like dates in this example. *Folders* can contain multiple *forms*, which in turn contain multiple *werte*. So my goal is this: *Get me all ids from folders, ordered by the werte column from the werte table*. Expect the *werte* column to contain a date string, so using *STR_TO_DATE(werte, '%d.%m.%Y')* is what is needed there.

A valid query to retrieve all *werte* fields containing a date would be

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(werte, '%d.%m.%Y') FROM werte where number = 2;
```

I just can't figure out how to put that together with the first query I talked about (selecting all *id*s from *folders*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would use `join`:

```
select f.*
from folders f join
     werte w
     on w.folder_id = f.id
where w.number = 2 
order by f.approved, str_to_date(werte, '%d.%m.%Y');
```

As a note:  if you are doing to store dates in strings, then use the ISO standard format YYYY-MM-DD.  If you used this format, the `str_to_date()` would be unnecessary, because an alphabetic ordering of the string representation would be correct.

Also, if there might not be a match in the `werte` table, then you should use `left join` instead of `inner join`.  The above assumes there is a match (or you only want rows that have a date).

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to avoid duplicates, you can use group by on the date:

```
SELECT f.id, STR_TO_DATE(w.werte, '%d.%m.%Y') as d 
 FROM folders f JOIN werte w
 ON w.folder_id = f.id
 GROUP BY d
 ORDER BY d;
```